# Shim a .bat file in Chocolatey

Tags: chocolatey

I'm trying to create a **self-contained chocolatey package** containing a .bat file (i.e. my "executable") that I want to shim onto the path. My `chocolateyinstall.ps1` file consists of the following:

```
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; # stop on all errors

    $toolsDir = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"

    Install-BinFile -Name 'test.bat' -Path $toolsDir
```

This creates the file `test.bat.exe` when the package is installed. But when I run the .exe file I get the error:

`Cannot find file at '..\lib\test-pkg\tools' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\test-pkg\tools). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.`

The directory mentioned (`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\test-pkg\tools`) definitely exists and contains the `test.bat` file, so the packaging and installation of the .bat file worked. As such, it looks to be a problem with the shim?

By way of experiment, I tried to shim a `.ps1` Powershell script in the same way, and got the same error message.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `-Path` parameter should have the full path to the bat file and not just to the `$toolsDir`, so something like this would work:

`Install-BinFile -Name 'test.bat' -Path "$toolsDir\test.bat"`

The surprising implication is that the shim target need not exist for the `Install-BinFile` to run without error.